# Pass a single event without ending date in full calendar

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am trying to render a event in the calendar with both start and ending date the same, i.e. I only intend to show a single line in the Day view of the calendar.

I tried 2 approaches;

First approach includes (an ajax call to a method that fetches a pair of innDateTime and outDateTime, then stores those two to a list which is sent to the calendar for rendering) This works however the behaviour is very untidy as it creates a block of inappropriate timeslot:

Index.cshtml:

//missing entry///

```
                      $.ajax({
                          url: baseUrl +  'Stats/missingEntryDayJsonReturn?EnrollNumber=' + event.id + '&StartDate=' + event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                          contenttype: 'application/json',
                          data: '',//JSON.stringify(params)
                          type: 'post'
                      }).done(function (data) {
                          console.log('bogus entry picked! ', data);

                          var calRes = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', data);
                      });
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult missingEntryDayJsonReturn(int EnrollNumber, string StartDate)
        {
            Calculations calc = new Calculations();
            List<Pair> logs = new List<Pair>();
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(StartDate);
            logs = calc.getSingleDevicePairs(EnrollNumber, dt, dt, 1);
            var eventList = from e in logs
                            select new
                            {
                                id = e.id,
                                title = "Time Spent : " + (e.OutDateTime - e.InnDateTime),
                                start = ((DateTime)e.InnDateTime).ToString("s"),
                                end = ((DateTime)e.OutDateTime).ToString("s"),
                                allDay = false
                            };
            var rows = eventList.ToArray();
            return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

  public List<Pair> getSingleDevicePairs(int EnrollNumber, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate, int? missingEntry)
{
if(missingEntry == 1)
{
   List<Pair> pairList = new List<Pair>();
 Pair missingPair = new Pair();
                var missingLog = db.AttendanceLogs.Where(x => x.RegisterationId == EnrollNumber && x.Date >= StartDate &&
              x.Date <= EndDate && x.isIgnore != true && x.CheckType == "In").OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();
                missingPair.InnDateTime = missingLog.DateTime;

missingPair.OutDateTime= missingLog.DateTime;
pairList.Add(missingPair);
                return pairList;  
}
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

This understood as I am passing a list, I'm now trying to pass only the start and single entry like:

```
   public ActionResult missingEntryDayJsonReturn(int EnrollNumber, string StartDate)
        {
 Calculations calc = new Calculations();
            Pair missingLog = new Pair();
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(StartDate);
            missingLog = calc.getMissingEntry(EnrollNumber, dt, dt);

            var eventList = from e in missingLog
                            select new
                            {
                                id = e.id,
                                title = "Invalid Punch: " + (e.OutDateTime - e.InnDateTime),
                                start = ((DateTime)e.InnDateTime).ToString("s"),
                                end = ((DateTime)e.OutDateTime).ToString("s"),
                                allDay = false
                            };
            var rows = eventList.ToArray();
            return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

> ^^ERROR: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for
>   source type 'Pair'.  'Select' not found.

```
 public Pair getMissingEntry(int EnrollNumber, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate)
        {
                Pair missingPair = new Pair();
                var missingLog = db.AttendanceLogs.Where(x => x.RegisterationId == EnrollNumber && x.Date >= StartDate &&
              x.Date <= EndDate && x.isIgnore != true && x.CheckType == "In").OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();
                missingPair.InnDateTime = missingLog.DateTime;
                return missingPair;          
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first approach is incorrect in the `if-clause`

Change this part:

```
if(missingEntry == 1)
{
   List<Pair> pairList = new List<Pair>();
 Pair missingPair = new Pair();
                var missingLog = db.AttendanceLogs.Where(x => x.RegisterationId == EnrollNumber && x.Date >= StartDate &&
              x.Date <= EndDate && x.isIgnore != true && x.CheckType == "In").OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();
                missingPair.InnDateTime = missingLog.DateTime;

missingPair.OutDateTime= missingLog.DateTime;
pairList.Add(missingPair);
                return pairList;  
}
```

To this part:

```
  if (missingEntry == 1)
            {
                Pair missingPair = new Pair();
                var missingLog = db.AttendanceLogs.Where(x => x.RegisterationId == EnrollNumber && x.Date >= StartDate &&
              x.Date <= EndDate && x.isIgnore != true).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();
                if (missingLog.CheckType == "In")
                {
                    missingPair.InnDateTime = missingLog.DateTime;
                    missingPair.OutDateTime = missingLog.DateTime.AddMinutes(1);
                    pairList.Add(missingPair);
                    return pairList;
                }
                else
                {
                    return pairList;
                }
            }
```

Why? because this query:

```
var missingLog = db.AttendanceLogs.Where(x => x.RegisterationId == EnrollNumber && x.Date >= StartDate &&
              x.Date <= EndDate && x.isIgnore != true && x.CheckType == "In").OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime).FirstOrDefault();
                missingPair.InnDateTime = missingLog.DateTime;
```

will always pick the last record from the db with the `CheckType` `In` regardless the fact which ones the last record. Plus this part:

```
missingPair.OutDateTime = missingLog.DateTime.AddMinutes(1);
```

is given for the event ending time.

Then inside your controller method:

```
  Calculations calc = new Calculations();
            List<Pair> logs = new List<Pair>();
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(StartDate);
            logs = calc.getSingleDevicePairs(EnrollNumber, dt, dt, 1);
            if (logs.Count > 0)
            {
                var eventList = from e in logs
                                select new
                                {
                                    id = e.id,
                                    start = ((DateTime)e.InnDateTime).ToString("s"),
                                    end = ((DateTime)e.OutDateTime).ToString("s"),
                                    allDay = false,
                                    color = "#FF0000"
                                };
                var rows = eventList.ToArray();
                return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
                return Json(0, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```